# Authentication fail error on convert Html to Pdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-to-pdf

I try to convert Html to PDF use "HtmlToPdf" nuget , It was work fine on local test but when i upload site to host i get this error :

```
 Conversion error: Authentication error.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: Conversion error: Authentication error.
```

This is my Convert method Code

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Convert(int id)
        {

            HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
            var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            string baseUrl = context.Request.Url.Host + ":"+context.Request.Url.Port + "/Doctor/DietTherapy/LineRegimePrint/";
            PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(baseUrl + id);

            // save pdf document
            byte[] pdf = doc.Save();

            // close pdf document
            doc.Close();

            // return resulted pdf document
            FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(pdf, "application/pdf");
            fileResult.FileDownloadName = "Document.pdf";
            return fileResult;
        }
```

How can i authorize user for this convert ?

Comment: what is `HtmlToPdf` class? Have you debugged it? do you know on what line the error actually occurs?

Comment: Are you looking for this?:  https://selectpdf.com/docs/WebPageAuthentication.htm

Comment: @trailmax HtmlToPdf is nuget module for convert html page to PDF , module work fine in local computer as i said later , just i have problem when i upload project to host , i think i should do something on authentication !

Comment: @David it seems solve my problem ! wait i check it

Comment: @David error was change to `Server Error in '/' Application.
Conversion error: Could not open url. `

Comment: @SaeedGholampoor: There's very little to go on here.  Is this error coming from the controller action you're showing us?  Or is it coming from the URL being invoked by the PDF library?  If the PDF library is saying "could not open URL" then that could literally mean anything.  Maybe use a tool like Fiddler to capture the exact HTTP request being made and response being received.

Comment: @David Your answer is right about authentication ,So you can post it.I try to resolve my second problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to [authenticate the request](https://selectpdf.com/docs/WebPageAuthentication.htm) being made by the PDF library.  For example, if it's using Basic HTTP Authentication:

```
HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
converter.Options.Authentication.Username = "some username";
converter.Options.Authentication.Password = "some password";
// the rest of your code...
```

The linked documentation also contains examples for other authentication methods.

Comment: Thanks for this answer , i can not resolve problem that i say in last comment.edit thrown from library.`Conversion error: Could not open url.` more :  `An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if you're getting the proper value on this line of code (when running on host server)?

```
string baseUrl = context.Request.Url.Host + ":"+context.Request.Url.Port + "/Doctor/DietTherapy/LineRegimePrint/";
```

Comment: i was change that line with direct link but same error : `string baseUrl = "http://www.mehrdiet.com/Doctor/DietTherapy/LineRegimePrint/";
            PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(baseUrl+id);`

Comment: my last error : Exception Details: System.Exception: Conversion error: Could not open url.

Source Error:

`An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. `

Comment: Are you sure?  What happen to the colon ":" in that code? The one before you call .Port  string baseUrl = context.Request.Url.Host + ":"+context.Request.Url.Port + "/Doctor/DietTherapy/LineRegimePrint/";

Comment: I don't see the ":" (from 'context.Request.Url.Host + ":"+context.Request.Url.Port') from what you said you got: "http://www.mehrdiet.com/Doctor/DietTherapy/LineRegimePrint/".  By looks of your code, it should return something like "http://www.mehrdiet.com:12345/Doctor/DietTherapy/LineRegimePrint/"

Answer (score 0):

While your development machine's IIS Express uses Anonymous Authentication, your hosting server is probably using Windows Authentication or other kinds. Check the IIS Managers to see the difference.

SelectPDF's library somehow creates a separate process to perform the HtmlToPdf conversion, which is outside the IUser, and therefore, the server asks for authentication.

For Windows Authentication setting, you may just use a generic user login account for this purpose and populate the required properties as mentioned in above thread and all would be fine.

```
converter.Options.Authentication.Username = "WindowsUser";
converter.Options.Authentication.Password = "WindowsPassword";
```